# How to get the value from list of dictionary create a function for this

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary which is having list of dictionary

- List of dictionary have of another list of dictionary
- I need to extract the values and append the into the list

I need to write a function. if the child is having `name` append to the parent list so that any list of dictionary pass through function will create a output as shown below

```
a = [{"id": "1", "Area": [{"id": "2", "name": "Clinical"},
                          {"id": "23", "name": "Delivery"}]},
     {"id": "2", "Area": [{"id": "2", "name": "Clinical"},
                          {"id": "23", "name": "Delivery"}]}]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[{"id": "1", "Area": ["Clinical", "Delivery"]},
 {"id": "2", "Area": ["Clinical", "Delivery"]}]
```

Code is below

```
result = []
temp = {}
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    templist = []
    b = a[i]['Area'][i]['name']
    c = a[i]['id']
    temp['id'] = c
    templist.append(b)
    temp['Area'] = templist
    result.append(temp)
    print (result)
```

My output is not extracting and put into a list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract values from list of dictionary and added to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63261202/how-to-extract-values-from-list-of-dictionary-and-added-to-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
result = [{'id': d['id'], 'Area': [nd['name'] for nd in d['Area']]} for d in a]
```

Comment: what if `a={ "id":"1", "Area":[ { "id":"2", "name":"Clinical" }, { "id":"23", "name":"Delivery" }], },{ "id":"2", "Area":[ { "id":"2", "name":"Clinical" }, { "id":"23", "name":"Delivery" }] } ` if dictionary only

Comment: how is it working for both, because for i in a: will go in to loop. but yur code is working fine how?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with dict and list comprehension

```
a=[{ "id":"1", "Area":[ { "id":"2", "name":"Clinical" }, 
                        { "id":"23", "name":"Delivery" }], },
   { "id":"2", "Area":[ { "id":"2", "name":"Clinical" }, 
                        { "id":"23", "name":"Delivery" }] } ]

res = dict(d, Area=[d2['name'] for d2 in d['Area']]) for d in a]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'id': '1', 'Area': ['Clinical', 'Delivery']}, 
 {'id': '2', 'Area': ['Clinical', 'Delivery']}]
```

Comment: what if a={ "id":"1", "Area":[ { "id":"2", "name":"Clinical" }, { "id":"23", "name":"Delivery" }], },{ "id":"2", "Area":[ { "id":"2", "name":"Clinical" }, { "id":"23", "name":"Delivery" }] }   mean  to say there is only dictionary not list of dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You put temp outside of the for loop, so temp is not reset during the loop. When you change the value of `id`, the value of `id` will be changed all over.

```
result = []
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    temp = {}
    templist = []
    b = a[i]['Area'][i]['name']
    c = a[i]['id']
    temp['id'] = c
    templist.append(b)
    temp['Area'] = templist
    result.append(temp)
print (result)
```